# implementing set theory operations in php

Tags: php, graph-theory, rbac, set-theory

How to implement set theory operations in pure php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Which operations are you looking for? What are you trying to accomplish?

In PHP an array is (imperfectly) analogous to a set, and PHP has [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (union), and [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) (complement) functions built in. There's also [`array_uintersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) and [`array_udiff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) for handling complex objects whose comparisons are not so straightforward.

Is there further functionality you need?

Comment: It's worth noting that array_merge isn't a true union according to set theory. You have to do array_merge then array_unique on the result otherwise you can end up with duplicates. The link that Strae provided in his answer to [Programming PHP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html) demonstrates this.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you'll already saw those links:

http://jamietalbot.com/2010/02/04/set-operations-in-php/

http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html

Comment: For comparing non-scalar values, such as stdClass objects and other data types.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20201021103045/http://jamietalbot.com/2010/02/04/set-operations-in-php/

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20080905054045/http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html